# Windows: What software do you recommend for editing MP3 ID3 tags?

Tags: windows, mp3, id3, tags

What software do you recommend for editing MP3 ID3 tags?

(The OS is Windows XP.)

Comment: Other than Windows Media Player?

Comment: i'd never recommend WMP for tag editing.  i rarely recommend it for anything...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use [MP3TAG](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/)

**Features:**

> Batch Tag Editing Write ID3v1.1,
>   ID3v2.3, ID3v2.4, MP4, WMA, APEv2 Tags
>   and Vorbis Comments to multiple files
>   at once.
>
> Support for Cover Art Download and add
>   album covers to your files and make
>   your library even more shiny.
>
> Import from Amazon, discogs, freedb
>   Save typing and import tags from
>   online databases like Amazon, discogs,
>   freedb and more.
>
> Replace characters or words Replace
>   strings in tags and filenames (with
>   support for Regular Expressions).
>
> Create Playlists automatically Create
>   and manage playlists automatically
>   while editing.
>
> Rename files from tags Rename files
>   based on the tag information and
>   import tags from filenames.
>
> Export to HTML, RTF, CSV Generate nice
>   reports and lists of your collection
>   based on user-defined templates.
>
> Full Unicode Support User-interface
>   and tagging are fully unicode
>   compliant.

Comment: Seconded. Worth mentioning that it requires .NET, though that's not much of an issue these days.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't noticed - possibly because I'm a .NET developer!

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? I was wondering about the down vote. .NET is a problem?

Comment: http://www.leniel.net/2010/05/mp3tag-to-batch-process-rename-mp3-tags.html

Answer (score 6):

I use the excellent [TagScanner](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/).

[image]

**Features:**

- Rename files based on the tag and file information
- Powerful multiple files tag editor
- Import tag information from an online databases like freedb or Amazon
- Manual text-search for information in freedb
- Generate tag information from file/foldernames
- Words replacement and case conversion from tags and filenames
- Full support for Unicode
- Supports MP3, OGG, Musepack, Monkey's Audio, FLAC, AAC, OptimFROG, SPEEX, WavePack, TrueAudio, WMA, MP4 files
- Supports ID3 1.0/1.1/2.2/2.3/2.4 tags, APE v1 and v2 tags, Vorbis Comments, WMA tags and MP4(iTunes) metadata
- Supports for embedded lyrics and cover art
- TAGs versions conversions
- Playlists editor
- Playlists export to HTML, Excel and CSV(e.g. for MySQL)
- Multilanguage interface
- Built-in multiformat player

Comment: How much does it cost?

Comment: Nothing! It's free :)

Answer (score 3):

I use [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com).

It's a decent ripper and player too.

Answer (score 2):

I like [PicardTagger](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardTagger), mainly because it uses **large** database of tags at http://musicbrainz.org. Once tagged, Picard can update changed tags.

It takes a while to get used to Picard, but it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I use TagScanner and it's pretty good. Crashes sometimes when it's searching for track info from the online DB's. MP3Tag. It's actually very good but there are minor issues:

- I'd like the ability to specify which fields to when pulling data from the online DB's.
- Parsing data from file names works but the parser is not that strong. For example I had multi-CD album with file names like 101-artist-trackname.mp3, 201-artist-trackname.mp3, etc, where the first digit = CD#, next two digits = track title. It worked for the most part but it would not parse the CD# and track# out. It treated all three digits as track # unless I told it the 1 was a constant. So i had to parse each CD one at time, with the CD# hardcoded. Would be nice to have RegEx or javascript support for all the text transforms.
- The UI is non-Windows native. I don't know what it's built in but none of the windows UI conventions work (keyboard shortcuts, etc). Took a little getting used to.
- Can't upload data into online track info DB's.

It's still the best I've used though. Haven't tried MP3Tag yet, I heard good things about it.

Answer (score 0):

I used [MP3 Collector](http://www.collectorz.com/mp3/) for a while. It was quite nice, but lately I've just been using [winamp](http://www.winamp.com), which has an option to mass tag entries in your media library using *ctrl-e*

I will check that MP3TAG over the weekend...

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [The Godfather](http://users.otenet.gr/~dtou20/).

It's old but and has not been updated in a long time, but it worked well and had a lot of powerfull features.