# Mp3 Tag Editor Open Source Windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, mp3, open-source, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: What software do you recommend for editing MP3 ID3 tags?](https://superuser.com/questions/5065/windows-what-software-do-you-recommend-for-editing-mp3-id3-tags)

Can someone inform me of an open source mp3 tag editor that is on Windows? Audacity doesn't let me clear the genre type so I'm not using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try **[Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/)** which is a quite successful universal tag editor.

Comment: I use MP3Tag and have found it to be very good.

Comment: the best free tag editor I know. But as far as I know it's not open source

Comment: After trying a couple of others, I found Mp3Tag and it is by far the best.

Answer (score 1):

The [MP3 Tag Tools](http://massid3lib.sourceforge.net/) seems to have what you're looking for.