# Is there a plugin or software that automatically identifies music tracks?

Tags: winamp, music-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-tagging MP3s](https://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s)

I have some unknown tracks which are named **Track - 1.mp3**, **Track - 2.mp3**.

Is there a plugin or some software which would allow me to automatically identify these files and preferably rename them? I play music on Winamp so a plugin would be nice if there is such a thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-tagging MP3s](http://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s) also see [Windows: What software do you recommend for editing MP3 ID3 tags?](http://superuser.com/questions/5065/windows-what-software-do-you-recommend-for-editing-mp3-id3-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is built into winamp.

http://blog.winamp.com/2009/08/03/clean-up-your-media-files-with-winamp/