# ID3 tagging by "/artistname/albumname" directory structure 

Tags: windows, mp3, id3

I have a large number of MP3s (> 10000) organized in a directory structure like

```
/Music/Artistname/Albumname/Trackname.mp3
```

Many of them are missing the correct ID3 tags for artist and album.

Does anybody know from own experience a tool that can do this automatically? A Windows solution would be preferred but I'd be ready to set up a Linux VM for this if some nifty shell script exists.

Comment: Do you want to set them automatically according to the folder names? Or would you be fine with tagging according to fingerprints? For the latter, we have plenty of questions here already, suggesting [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) (cba to find the duplicates now).

Comment: check out [musicbrainz picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) it's really popular and I think it can do what you want

Comment: @slhck, Raystafarian thanks, but they've been ripped CD-wise and I have often removed those songs I didn't like, so I guess album fingerprinting won't work. A solution that automatically sets them according to the directory structure is probably the only way to go.

Comment: If you use picard, you'd want to group the tracks in the same album together. In this case, and with the number of files and the organisation of the files, using the path seems to be a faster option, IMO.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/5065/windows-what-software-do-you-recommend-for-editing-mp3-id3-tags http://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s

Answer (score 4):

[MP3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) would do it - using the filename to tag option, and using a partial path.

For example:

```
e:/music/%artistname%/%albumname%/%trackname%
```

It's one of the situations that's in the [MP3tag manual](http://help.mp3tag.de/main_converter.html#ftt).

Comment: This looks promising, thanks very much! I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [**easytag**](http://projects.gnome.org/easytag). I used it to tag all my 20GB+ music collections.

If you have the same structure for all your music (for example, everything is "Artist/Year - Album/Track# - Title") you can tag everything in just a few clicks.

It requires GTK runtime for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to tag MP3 files by its directory structure

Use foobar2000 together with its plugin masstagger

```
|__ 1st folder = artist  
   |__ 2nd folder = album  
      |__ file name  = track 1
      |__ file name  = track 2
```

1. Download & install [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) (preferable in portable mode)
2. Start foobar and drag & drop your music files into its main window
3. Download [masstagger](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_masstag) plugin
4. Install masstagger via `Foobar → File → Preferences → Components → Install`
5. Select all music files, right-click them and choose: `Tagging → Manage Scripts`
6. Add the following three lines

   ```
   Guess values from other fields
   Source format:     $directory(%path%,2)
   Guessing pattern:  %artist%

   Guess values from other fields
   Source format:     $directory(%path%,1)
   Guessing pattern:  %album%

   Guess values from filename
   Scheme:            %title%
   ```

   It should look like this (thats the important part)
   [image]
7. Click run & be happy