# Audio File - No Album Property

Tags: windows, audio, mp4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: What software do you recommend for editing MP3 ID3 tags?](https://superuser.com/questions/5065/windows-what-software-do-you-recommend-for-editing-mp3-id3-tags)

I have an audio file with no Album attached to it. Figured I could go into the Properties + Details and change it but it seems to be missing the "Album" field. Has Artist, Genre and Year but no Album. Is there a way I can add a field to this file with Album?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use any mp3 tag editor. They will let you edit all the tags.

An ideal example would be [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html) but there are a range of others, including mp3edit, mp3magic etc.

Comment: If you could throw links in here that would be awesome ^_^